# How to get systemd "socket" unit to automatically restart? specifically dropbear.socket

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, systemd

On my BeagleBone Black Angstrom system, the `dropbear.socket` UNIT seems to spontaneously die after a while. The effect is that I can not `ssh` into the machine without restarting the `dropbear.socket` UNIT.  This fixes the problem in the short term:

```
systemctl restart dropbear.socket
```

I tried adding `Restart=always` to the `/lib/systemd/system/dropbear.socket` file, but that is not allowed (I get an error in the system log).

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=dropbear.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=22
Accept=yes
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
Also=dropbearkey.service
```

What's the correct way of getting `dropbear.socket` to restart automatically? It would be nice to fix the root cause, but this seems like an easy workaround and will make the system more robust.

## Update

Here is the list of failed units (I didn't filter it, in case the music service (which I am not using) is a suspect).

```
% systemctl list-units --failed --full
UNIT                                                  LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
dropbear@1-192.168.0.43:22-192.168.0.40:55370.service loaded failed failed SSH Per-Connection Server
mpd.service                                           loaded failed failed Music Player Daemon

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

2 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Also here is `/lib/systemd/system/dropbear@.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH Per-Connection Server
Requires=dropbearkey.service
After=syslog.target dropbearkey.service

[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/sbin/dropbear -i -r /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key -p 22
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
StandardInput=socket
KillMode=process
```

Comment: That's not the service.  It's a _socket_ unit.  A _service_ will be named `dropbear@0-127.0.0.1:22-127.0.0.1:37855.service` or similar and is one of a set of services generated from the _service template_ `dropbear@.service`.  You can help answerers by putting the output of `systemctl list-units --failed --full|fgrep dropbear@` into your question, or somewhere that they can read it.

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks for the clarification. Does my edit to the question help

Comment: What is the error message which follows the Restart=Always statement?

Comment: It will, and has.  It helped me to eliminate one answer.  (-:

Comment: I've created an upstream issue: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11553

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the OnFailure flag? Example:

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=dropbear.service
OnFailure=dropbear.socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=22
Accept=yes
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
Also=dropbearkey.service
```

Comment: OnFailure did not work for me. systemd says "foo.socket: Dependency OnFailure=foo.socket dropped"